# $a_n$ does not have an upper bound$\iff a_n$ has a subsequence which diverges to infinity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $a_n$ be a sequence. *(Prove or disprove)*

> $a_n$ does not have an upper bound$\iff a_n$ has a subsequence which diverges to infinity

*Progress:*
$\Rightarrow\quad$
$a_n$ does not have an upper bound $\implies$ there exists an increasing monotonic subsequence which diverges to infinity.

$\Leftarrow$
Let $a_{n_j}$ be a subsequence of $a_n$. Since, $\lim_{j\to\infty}a_{n_j}=\infty$ we get:$$
\forall M\in\mathbb{R}\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\quad\forall j\in\mathbb{N}\quad j>N\quad a_{n_j}>M
$$

Comment: :$a_n$ does not have an upper bound" is easier to read. Also, where is $a_n$ hanging out? in $\mathbb R$, I assume.

Comment: For $\Longleftarrow$, you've written down what it means for $a_{n_j}$ to go to infinity as $j$ goes to infinity. Cool. Now use that to disprove "$a_n$ is bounded". $\implies$ doesn't seem to have much progress yet. Start with what "$a_n$ is bounded" means, mathematically, and then construct your subsequence.

Comment: Yes, in $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 0):

A hint: you can define a subsequence $n_i$ by induction.  Start with $n_1=1$; now for each $i$, the set $\{a_{n_0}, a_{n_1}, \ldots, a_{n_i}\}$ is finite and so it has an upper bound $U$; since $a_n$ is unbounded you can find some $n_U\gt n_i$ with $a_{n_U}\gt U$ (why?). Now, let $n_{i+1}=n_U$.

Note that the above argument doesn't work *quite* as given, because while you've guaranteed that $a_{n_i}$ is an increasing subsequence, you *haven't* shown that it's unbounded (and indeed, it doesn't necessarily have to be).  But a small modification of this argument will work; you just have to choose $n_U$ such that $a_{n_U}$ is not just $\gt U$ but also greater than the $i$'th member of some (almost arbitrary) sequence which tends to infinity. You should be able to show that this is still possible, and then show that this implies the unboundedness of your subsequence $a_{n_i}$...